# Android studio task runs on every build

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

[This is the an image from Android Studio's build analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKHm3.png)

I believe this is the cause of my exceptionally long build times. My builds take close to 30mins in this project. Can anyone help resolve the issue?

Comment: According to your image this tasks takes 3ms ...

Comment: Okay @Henry. I'm not sure about that but the overall build of the app is what is stated in the question. 35mins to be precise

Comment: Could you add (excerpts of) your `build.gradle` file(s) to your question?

Comment: I had to delete the project from my computer and clone it again. There was a weird bug. The project had grown to 5.76GB. I'm wondering what could have caused that. If anyone has an idea, I would love to hear it. Thanks